# License alert message for mysite.com, but not www.mysite.com

Tags: control-panel, license

I have a client website that is reachable at www.mysite.com and mysite.com. Everything on the site functions fine, and the Craft CP can be accessed at either www.mysite.com/admin and mysite.com/admin.

When accessed form mysite.com/admin, the user gets the "The license located at config/license.key belongs to mysite.com. Transfer it to this domain?" message.

This hasn't affected anything yet, but I'm worried that Craft might suspend the license because of the two different domains. It is also worrying the client anytime they login at mysite.com/admin.

Any tips on how to permanently clear the message on both domains, or somehow let the licesne know that it is the same site on both www.mysite.com and mysite.com?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm worried that Craft might suspend the license because of the two different domains.

That will never happen, but from what you're describing you shouldn't be getting that alert.

Can you hit up support@buildwithcraft.com with some details about the domain name?

Regardless, you should probably be picking one of those (domain.com or www.domain.com) and forcing the other domain to redirect to it for [SEO reasons](https://www.mattcutts.com/blog/seo-advice-url-canonicalization/).  Otherwise, the all-mighty Google will treat them as two different domains.